# HTTP + JSON simple api request being sent as blank

Tags: javascript, html, json, http

I am trying to make a simple API request and failing miserably.

The documentation says this is how to make the request:

```
POST https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token
--------------------------------------

{
  "client_id": "### Your client_id ###",
  "client_secret": "### Your client_secret ###",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

I tried submitting this through an HTML form like so just to test:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8">
</head>


<?php


$json ='{"client_id": "creds",
"client_secret": "secret",
"grant_type": "client_credentials"}';



print_r($_POST);
?>

<form action="https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token" enctype='application/json' method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="post_data" <?php echo 'value="'.htmlspecialchars($json).'"'; ?> />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I was told that the content-type needs to be `application/json` which I have set.

I am doing this on my server via a PHP test file but really I am open to having this work in any way possible and then figuring it out from there.

When I submit from my current HTML form the page redirects to yotpo page, and the JSON data appears to be blank:

```
{"status":{"message":"Couldn't find Account with app_key = ","code":404,"error_type":"Exceptions::RecordNotFound"}}
```

What is the simplest way to submit this API authentication?

Comment: _I was told that the content-type needs to be application/json which I have set._ Nope. You haven't set that. `enctype` attribute cannot make Content-type to be `application/json`. It can only be set to either of [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type) types which `application/json` not belong to. In other words you cannot send JSON as `form` data. You have to use AJAX to send such data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

> should all my interactions with the api be done using curl and php? Or
>   is it "safe" to just use html/jquery to interact with the api now that
>   the credentials are being generated in a safe way.

Well its not safe to use client side for getting authorizations like this case. Even after getting `token`, I won't use them at client side for anything. Instead I would create some PHP pages/api, which javascript(ajax or something) will call it and get the job done!

> the return access_token is given to me in a JSON format. How can I use
>   the given access token within the jquery i will use? I think I will
>   need json_decode correct?

Please see updated code. If you still want to use `token` in jquery, follow steps below:

1. Create php api, `/auth` which does authorization and echoes `token`.
2. Make some request(post, get) to `/auth`, that will return `token`. Save it and use it.

---

Problem is your are posting data as `post_data`. So at receiving end, it will be like `post_data = {...}` which they are not looking at for apiKey.

Also it is not safe to expose private keys in public. You can use pure PHP cURL request to get authorization.

Try this:

```
<?php
$json = array(
    "client_id"=> "creds",
    "client_secret"=> "secret",
    "grant_type"=> "client_credentials"
);
$ch = curl_init( "https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token" );

# Setup request to send json via POST.
$payload = json_encode( $json );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

# Send request.
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

# Print response.
#echo "<pre>$result</pre>";

# use json_decode method to parse result.
$auth = json_decode($result, true);
echo $auth['access_token']; # Prints token

# For debugging, use var_dump($auth);    

?>
```

Now you can make a connection file, which will get authorization keys, then all other php files can share it.

Checkout phpfiddle example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mpd1-swcn

Comment: Ok thank you so much for this. It works. I have a very basic understanding of curl to begin with so this looks pretty confusing to me but I do understand what is going on. I have 2 questions now that come from this, 1. should all my interactions with the api be done using curl and php? Or is it "safe" to just use html/jquery to interact with the api now that the credentials are being generated in a safe way. and 2. the return access_token is given to me in a JSON format. How can I use the given access token within the jquery i will use? I think I will need json_decode correct?

Comment: @Sackling Please see the updated answer. Hope it clarify your doubts!

Answer (score 2):

Attach a JavaScript function to your button that does an HTTP request

I recommend that you use JQuery to make the request for you. If don't use it you will have to make individual code for every browser.

If you use JQuery you will use an code similar to this

```
var data = '{"client_id": "creds",
"client_secret": "secret",
"grant_type": "client_credentials"}'

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token",
  data: data,
  success: function(){"worked"},
  dataType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Your claim that you need JQuery for AJAX due to compatibility issues is like 5 years out of date.

Comment: If you don't use jquery, you will have to use xmlhttprequest, and you will have problem with a lot of stuff, i recommend use AJAX for the request.

Comment: AJAX is a technology, AJAX is not jquery. Could you name any problem I could possibly have?

Comment: You can use AJAX without jquery without problems

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete example of how to do it with javascript. However, take note of Priyesh Kumar's answer! **Putting your client secret ID in HTML is dangerous**. Unless this is your internal tool, use PHP not javascript.

```js
   document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        // prevent normal submit
        e.preventDefault();
        e.cancelBubble = true;

        // test if JSON is valid
        var validJSON;
        try {
            validJSON = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.elements["post_data"].value));
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Invalid json");
            console.log(e);
            return;
        }
        // Mark field as disabled
        var form = this;
        form.elements["submit"].disabled = true;
        form.elements["submit"].value = "Loading...";
        // Send AJAX
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", this.action, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        // this runs after load
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (data) {
            // print result
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("result").appendChild(new Text(this.responseText));
            // 
            form.elements["submit"].removeAttribute("disabled");
            form.elements["submit"].value = "Submit";
        });


        // this sends JSON
        xhr.send(validJSON);
    });
```

```html
<form action="https://api.yotpo.com/oauth/token" id="myform" enctype='application/json' method="POST">

<!-- DO NOT POST YOUR CLIENT SECRET PUBLICLY!
     that's why it's called secret!
-->
    <textarea name="post_data" style="width:100%">
{ "client_id": "creds",
        "client_secret": "secret",
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```